# How can I restore value when mouse leaves texbox in VB?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, click, mouseevent

My textbox has a default value of "0,00". My code clears the textbox when it is clicked.

```
  Private Sub Pop1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Pop1.MouseDown
    Pop1.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Now I want to make a code that puts default value (0,00) back if texbox is left blank when leaving the textbox - clicking on other item.

Comment: You want to handle the `Blur` event, check if the textbox is empty, and if it is - set the value to your default.

Comment: @vcsjones I'm not really sure how to do that, can you edit my code? I'm a newbie programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the Leave event of the Text box and set it back to the default if it's blank.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    If Me.TextBox1.Text.Equals(String.Empty) Then
        Me.TextBox1.Text = "0,00"
    End If
End Sub
```